# Safari browser error using css animation scale and css transition in same time

Tags: css, debugging, safari, scale

I have created a new login form with animations
This login form is animated at each stage of the connection

My animation work on all browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera, Brave, Firefox) except Safari. But actually the css work perfectly if i deactivate and reactivate keyframe (and -webkit) in the Safari browser inspector.
Until now I have not managed to find a solution.

I tried to use css "zoom" , but it doesn't work with animation.
The issue is located when you fill login (almost 8 char) and password (almost 10 char) = checked icon must be in normal position and animated with scale.

Can you help me ?

```
.submit-btn img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transform: scale(0.3) rotate(0deg);
  transition: 1s all;
}
.validated_img {
  -webkit-animation: 1s linear 0s infinite alternate animcheck;
  animation: 1s linear 0s infinite alternate animcheck;
  cursor:pointer;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animcheck {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animcheck {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.3) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0.4) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved : Safari can't used at the same time the transform scale animation and transition.
I'm obliged to delete transition:1s all; to .submit-btn img.